# Accurately determine the type of OS PHP is running on

Tags: php, operating-system, uname

I need to determine the type of OS the PHP server is running on.
By type, I mean strings like "windows" or "linux", not "wince", "winnt" etc.

So far, I have to leads: PHP_OS and uname(), the later being more reliable than the earlier  (PHP_OS says what OS PHP was built on - according to documentation).

Comment: Does `php_uname()` not fulfill your requirement? If not, why not?

Comment: I need the OS type, but php_uname returns a lot of extra details which makes detection hard (eg: winnt vs wince vs darwin => windows windows osx). Plus, I also don't (can't) know all types of strings I can get. For instance, I don't run solaris or bsd - and at this point it is impossible to run my own php on those systems.

Comment: @Christian this seems to be one of the things that look totally easy, but at the same time are impossible to do 100% reliably. Care to elaborate what exactly you need this for? Maybe that leads to an idea about some perfect indicator

Comment: @Pekka - It's a generic function to distinguish between OSes. I want a guy detecting hpux to be able to this as easily as the guy detecting windows. Predictable results are relatively important.

Comment: @Christian hmm, the only idea that comes to mind is to open a Community Wiki question asking people to report what `uname()` returns on their system. I imagine it's going to be relatively consistent on Unixes/Linuxes where there actually *is* a built-in uname(), and I'm sure it follows some sort of convention on Windowses as well. It's just going to be a question of collecting as many possible outcomes as possible. Let me know if you decide to do this, I can contribute info on Win7, Server 2003 and 2008

Comment: @Pekka - That is actually an excellent idea. I never did this before, but is it possible to involve serverfault users as well? Sounds like lots of people from there have access to this info.

Comment: @Christian good idea, but SO's strict rules about duplicate will make it difficult to ask the same question on both sites. I would focus on one site - Serverfault could be a good pick too, but it may have more traction on SO

Comment: OK, but how do I do the community question thingy?

Comment: @Christian ask it and tick the "Community Wiki" checkbox in the form

Comment: Hmm, I suspect I don't have enough score to do this - I don't see that tick box.

Comment: @Christian oh, indeed, I don't see it either. Wtf? Hang on, I'll check

Comment: @Christian there has been a [recent change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down). I'd ask it as a normal question and if anybody complains that it should be CW, point them to that page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's important to know that no non-Windows OS string is going to contain the text "win", and no non-OSX OS string is going to contain the word "darwin", and so on. Detecting the OS is easy.

```
$uname = strtolower(php_uname());
if (strpos($uname, "darwin") !== false) {
    // It's OSX
} else if (strpos($uname, "win") !== false) {
    // It's windows
} else if (strpos($uname, "linux") !== false) {
    // It's Linux
} else {
    // It's something your script won't run on
}
```

Comment: It detects OSX as windows ;-). I've got this code already, but as I said, it ain't reliable.

Comment: Now I'm not calling you a liar or crazy, but that sounds impossible! haha

Comment: P.S. Note the order of the if than statements. It will grab the "win" in "darwin" if you're checking for OSX first.

Comment: Oh and by the way, do you know the above conditionals for other OSes (hpux, xenix, haiku...)?

Comment: With regards to your PS, that is exactly why I replied so above. It will see "win" in "darwin" and think it is "windows".

Comment: "With regards to your PS, that is exactly why I replied so above. It will see "win" in "darwin" and think it is "windows"." Er, no. This is why you first check for windows. If the first if/then statement is satisfied, the rest are ignored. If will only check the "darwin" string if the windows string failed.

Comment: As far as other OS's.. There's no point in checking for OS's that PHP can't even be installed on.

Comment: Pseudocode 1: "windows" contains "win"? Yes, therefore it is windows.   Pseudocode 2: "darwin" contains "win"? Yes, therefore it is windows.

Comment: the correct order would be: check for "darwin", check for "win", check for "linux"...

Comment: slosd is right. You DO need to check for Darwin first. My bad ;)

Comment: Tehehe. Just edit the code and we'll try to forget it ever happened :P

Comment: ahah Well now that you wrote that I can't! Maybe next time. ;)

Comment: Instead of `if (strpos($uname, "win") !== false)` you can say `if (strpos($uname, "win") === 0)` to check that the string _starts_ with "win" and doesn't match "darwin".