# What does YOUR uname say?

Tags: php, operating-system, uname

**Short story:** I need to write a PHP script which finds the correct OS type from uname (eg: both `wince` and `winnt` would return `windows`). [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948567/accurately-determine-the-type-of-os-php-is-running-on) for more info.

**Shouldn't this be a community wiki?**

Yes but...[see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down).

**How to help:** If your OS is not listed below, please run this code and share your findings:

```
<?php
    echo php_uname();
?>
```

Or, in a Unix shell, try

```
user@host ~ > php -a

php > echo php_uname();
```

**List of shared results**

- Darwin ... 10.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: Fri Apr 23 18:28:53 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
- Darwin ... 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
- Windows NT ... 6.1 build 7600
- Linux ... 2.6.24-24-xen #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 18:15:39 UTC 2009 x86_64
- Linux ... 2.6.34.7-56.fc13.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 15 03:36:55 UTC 2010 x86_64
- Linux ... 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 20:26:08 UTC 2010 i686
- Windows NT ... 5.1 build 2600
- Windows NT ... 6.0 build 6002 (Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 2) i586
- Windows NT ... 6.1 build 7600 ((null)) i586

It's interesting to note that even when certain conditions match exactly, uname still produces different results.

Comment: @Christian I suggest opening up a chatroom for this - it's more suitable for this. A chatroom can be automatically created for this question using this link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/questions/3948866/what-does-your-uname-say

Comment: Aren't chatrooms temporary? I'd like this to stay current so people may use results as they wish.

Comment: Why don't you use php_uname('s')?

Comment: @YiJiang why? This is potentially useful information for future generations as well

Comment: @sharth `s` is a subset of the full info string and may vary e.g. across different Windowses. Finding out what it contains is the point of this exercise

Comment: @Pekka On second thought, you're right, this would be more permanent.

Comment: sharth - That still produces mixed results.

Comment: @imgx64 - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down

Comment: Seems this *may* be useful, but a CW edited **answer** would probably be the best place to put the results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738823/possible-values-for-php-os

Comment: Tim, since I can't see that coming soon, we could keep getting answers here, migrate to the wiki at some point, and then close/delete this question.

Comment: As far as I can tell from a bit of googling, this list (both for PHP_OS and php_uname) has been compiled on stackoverflow a half a dozen times already.

Comment: Number one and number three are exactly the same.

Comment: @mellowsoon can you post some links? I wasn't able to find any through the search

Comment: @Christian - Feel free to edit mine, I've combined a few of the other answers to start the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948866/what-does-your-uname-say/3948945#3948945

Comment: If 2 more people edit this question it will become CW automatically or you can flag for a mod to make it CW.

Comment: This is a bit like looking at browser user agent strings. There's all of 5-6 popular browsers on the market, but 10k different user agent strings.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like this is the browscap for uname. **Feel free to edit/update this list**:

- Ubuntu 10.10 32bit (i686)

```
Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.35-22-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP SYSTEM_DATE i686
```

- Ubuntu 10.04 32bit, PHP 5.3.2

```
Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP SySTEM_DATE i686
```

- Ubuntu 10.04 x64

```
Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP SYSTEM_DATE x86_64t
```

- Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64

```
Linux SYSTEM_NAME 3.8.0-29-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP SYSTEM_DATE x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- Debian GNU/Linux 4.0 (etch) 32bit, PHP 5.2.0

```
Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.18-028stab062.3 #1 SMP SYSTEM_DATE i686
```

- Gentoo linux, 32bit, PHP 5.2:

```
Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.35-gentoo-r8sh #1 SMP PREEMPT SYSTEM_DATE i686
```

- Fedora 13 64 bits:

```
Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.34.7-56.fc13.x86_64 #1 SMP SYSTEM_DATE x86_64
```

- Centos 5.5 x86:

```
Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.18-194.17.1.el5 #1 SMP SYSTEM_DATE i686
```

- Mac OS Snow Leopard (imac 24")

```
Darwin SYSTEM_NAME.local 10.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: SYSTEM_DATE; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, PHP 5.3 32-Bit:

```
Windows NT SYSTEM_NAME 6.1 build 7600 ((null)) i586
```

- Windows 2008 Server 64-Bit

```
Windows NT SYSTEM_NAME 6.0 build 6002 (Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 2) i586
```

- Windows XP SP3

```
Windows NT SYSTEM_NAME 5.1 build 2600
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, PHP 5.3 32-Bit:

```
Windows NT *Name of my machine* 6.1 build 7600 ((null)) i586
```

Comment: Why do it says "Windows NT" when you are running Windows 7? Same for me for Windows 10.

Comment: @OmarTariq historical reasons - Windows NT was a parallel development to Windows 3.x and 95, which were based on DOS, while NT was a completely new OS for servers, much more stable. The NT core eventually became the basis for all editions of Windows (I think from Windows XP onwards)

Answer (score 1):

Gentoo linux, 32bit, PHP 5.2:

```
Linux office 2.6.35-gentoo-r8sh #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 28 13:35:58 EEST 2010 i686
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X 10.6.4, php 5.3.2

```
Darwin [myMachineName] 10.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: Fri Apr 23 18:28:53 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Comment: Was gonna paste mine, but it matches this exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 2008 Server 64-Bit, PHP 5.2 32-Bit both through Apache and in CLI:

```
Windows NT *Name of machine* 6.0 build 6002 (Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 2) i586
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS Snow Leopard (imac 24")

```
Darwin XXXXXXX-YYYYYYY.local 10.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: Fri Apr 23 18:28:53 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Where XXXX-YYYY is my name and surname

Windows XP SP3

```
Windows NT XXXXXX 5.1 build 2600
```

where XXXXX is machine name

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 13 64 bits:

```
greg@liche :) ~ > php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo php_uname();
Linux liche.gregnet 2.6.34.7-56.fc13.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 15 03:36:55 UTC 2010 x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.4 32bit, PHP 5.3.2

> Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP SYSTEM_TIME i686

Debian GNU/Linux 4.0 (etch) 32bit, PHP 5.2.0

> Linux SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.18-028stab062.3 #1 SMP SYSTEM_TIME i686

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04, 64 bit, with PHP Version 5.3.2:

`Linux MY_SYSTEM_NAME 2.6.32-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 17 20:05:27 UTC 2010 x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 32bit (i686)

PHP version

```
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 15 2010 14:17:04)
```

Output:

```
Linux lenovo-t60 2.6.35-22-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Sun Oct 10 09:24:00 UTC 2010 i686
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 64bit, PHP 5.3.3:

> Linux *name of machine* 2.6.35-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP SYSTEM_TIME x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Centos 5.5 x86:

```
Linux <hostname>.<domainname> 2.6.18-194.17.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Sep 29 12:51:33 EDT 2010 i686
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 64bit with php-5.3.3-nts-Win32-VC9-x86

```
Windows NT <name> 6.1 build 7600 (Unknow Windows version Ultimate Edition) i586
```

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin(32-bit install) running on Windows 10 64-bit, running PHP 5.6.17

```
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW win8-testing-vm 2.4.1(0.293/5/3) 2016-01-24 11:24 i686
```

Comment: The “OS” section (`CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW`) has a different format from Windows. It could have been `Cygwin NT 10.0 WoW` which is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

macOS (a.k.a. Mac OS X) Sierra 10.12.2 on a MacBookPro11,1

```
Darwin myhostname 16.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.3.0: Thu Nov 17 20:23:58 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.31.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little bits to puzzle ..

Windows NT is kernel/platform branch name, yes, it is confusing a bit to see "NT 6.2" tag referring to Windows 8 Pro .
Windows version tags are quite well documented over here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions

For a curiosity, this is my Debian Stretch running as WLS (Windows Linux Subsystem) inside Windows 10 Pro x64 (system info on those Win10 states "Version 10.0.19042")

```
Linux SILVERSTONE 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #488-Microsoft Mon Sep 01 13:43:00 PST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```